# I can't get shortcutItem. The value of the userInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c

3DTouch

this plist

```
<dict>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
        <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeShare</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
        <string>share</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
        <string>UITouchText.share</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemUserInfo</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>url</key>
        <string>value1</string>
    </dict>
```

and in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler
```

i want to get shortcutItem.userInfo

```
if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"UITouchText.share"])
{
      NSLog(@"%@",shortcutItem.userInfo[@"url"]);  
}
```

but The dictionary to return empty

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry  , this plist  is wrong.

```
<dict>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
        <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeShare</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
        <string>share</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
        <string>UITouchText.share</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemUserInfo</key>
        <dict>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>value1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

open as property list

this is wrong
[image: This is wrong]
this is true
[image: This is true]